# C#. Вопрос по работе с пространствами имен

Tags: c#, .net, namespace

Доброго времени суток!

Есть решение под названием `RiskAssessment`. В нем есть 2 проекта:

1) RiskAssessment.User, в котором находится файл `User.cs`

2) RiskAssessment.Risk, в котором находится файл `Risk.cs`

Risk.cs:

```
using System;

namespace RiskAssessment.Risk
{
    public class Risk
    {
        //SomeContent
    }
}
```

User.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using RiskAssessment.Risk;

namespace RiskAssessment.User
{
    public class User
    {
        List<Risk> risks;
    }
}
```

Код файла `User.cs` не будет компилироваться, потому как для обращения к типу `Risk` требуется следующая ссылка:

```
List<RiskAssessment.Risk.Risk> risks;
// или
List<Risk.Risk>
```

Почему нельзя обратиться к типу `Risk`, используя просто `Risk`? Как исправить наименования пространств имен, чтобы доступ к типу `Risk` был через `Risk`, а не через `Risk.Risk`. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этим.

Comment: А за что минус, кстати? Хороший валидный вопрос на тонкости name resolution в C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас пространство имён (namespace) и класс имеют одинаковое имя. Это не рекомендуется [по многим причинам](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/).

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
namespace RiskAssessment.RiskObjects
{
    public class Risk
    {
        //SomeContent
    }
}
```

```
using RiskAssessment.RiskObjects;

namespace RiskAssessment.UserObjects
{
    public class User
    {
        List<Risk> risks;
    }
}
```

---

Дело в том, что алгоритм поиска имён в C# сначала ищет `Risk` в `RiskAssessment.User` (и не находит), затем идёт наружу и ищет в `RiskAssessment`. Там он находит `User`, но это namespace, так что он не ищет дальше, а выдаёт ошибку.

До рассмотрения `using` дело даже не доходит.

(Точный алгоритм поиска описан в спецификации языка, раздел 3.8.)

---

Обновление: Внимательно перечитав алгоритм разрешения имён, я нашёл ещё одно решение, которое работает без переименования:

```
namespace RiskAssessment.User
{
    using RiskAssessment.Risk; // <-- *внутри*

    public class User
    {
        List<Risk> risks;
    }
}
```

Здесь алгоритм разрешения имён «видит» имя класса `Risk`, так как оно импортировано во внутреннее пространство имён `RiskAssessment.User`, и таким образом до «спуска» в пространство имён `RiskAssessment` дело не доходит.

Тем не менее, всё же совпадающее имя пространства имён и класса — не самая хорошая вещь, так что возможно переименование пространства имён всё же лучше.

Comment: Да, это решает мою проблему, спасибо!
Хочу задать еще один вопрос: есть ли какое-либо соглашение по именованию namespace'ов в таких случаях? Вы предложили добавить постфикс `Objects`, но ведь объявляются в namespace'ах не объекты, а типы. Не лучше ли будет назвать пространство имен `RiskTypes` или хотя бы `RiskEntities`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Да, вы правы, `RiskEntities` звучит лучше. Я не знаю о каком-либо соглашении по этому поводу, к сожалению.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Посмотрите на обновление ответа.

Comment: интересное решение, возьму на вооружение! Но все же я пришел к тому, что лучше не допускать совпадений в названии классов и пространств имен.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Да, так будет правильнее. Спасибо за отличный вопрос!