# Не работает using

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net, using

Потребовалось работать с .NET Core, раньше работал с .NET Framework.
Создал консольный проект .NET Core, но `using System;` в нём не работает (в VS код бледный и подсказка, что директива не нужна).
Из-за чего даже обычный `Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");` выдаёт ошибку, что отсутствует ссылка на сборку.
Я понимаю, что можно написать `System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");`, но всё же как использовать System через using ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В Гугле наткнулся, что может быть нет каких-то зависимостей, а какие они должны быть?
Так же заметил, что если вручную начать писать `Console` и студия предложит "дописать". То код станет `System.Console`. Может так и должно быть в Core?

Comment: Студия багует скорее всего, попробуй решение перестроить / студию перезапустить.

Comment: и решение перестраивал и заново проект делал, даже на всякий случай ПК перезагружал. Всё равно ошибка

Comment: Систему переустановить еще нужно, точно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё дело было в названии проекта Life.Console, VS ругался из-за .Console

Comment: Распространенная проблема с использованием неймспейсов

Comment: Подробнее об этом рассказано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654143/212981)